# WebP - auto creation on server?

Tags: wordpress, image, .htaccess, webp

I've been experimenting with webp lately and I'm loving it. I've setup the server [via htaccess](http://mikevoermans.com/apache/serving-right-image-htaccess-webp) to check whether a WEBP version of an image exists whenever a PNG or JPG is requested and if the WEBP file is present, serves that image instead for browsers which support WEBP.

I currently use WordPress on most of my sites. What I'm doing at the moment is downloading the uploads folder of existing sites, [running it through XnConvert](http://dirk.stasche.it/wordpress/meet-and-deploy-webp-created-to-make-your-wordpress-page-that-extra-bit-zippier) to convert to webp and then reuploading.

Does anyone know if it would be possible to auto create webp versions of images on image upload? Preferably with webp versions of all the thumbnails generated too. I've googled around but can't find anything on auto creation / compressing on the server.